# How to replace image set with new set of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here i have created a image slider kind of thing with 3 images initially, where clicking on pre/next button will replace the prev next image.

I want clicking on prev/next button should completely replace the images with prev/next 3 images(not just one).

```
var stPt = 0, elToShow = 10; //showing 10 elements

var $ul = $('ul.ice-navigator');
var $li = $('ul.ice-navigator li'); //get the list of li's
var $copy_li = [];
var copy_lgt = $li.length - elToShow;

//call to set thumbnails based on what is set
initNav();
function initNav() {
var tmp;
for (var i = elToShow; i < $li.length; i++) {
  tmp = $li.eq(i);
  $copy_li.push(tmp.clone());
  tmp.remove();
  }
}

$('.ice-next').click (function () {
$li = $('ul.ice-navigator li'); //get the list of li's

//move the 1st element clone to the last position in copy_li
$copy_li.splice(copy_lgt, 0, $li.eq(0).clone() );          //array.splice(index,howmany,element1,.....,elementX)

//kill the 1st element in the UL
$li.eq(0).remove();

//add to the last
$ul.append($copy_li.shift());
});

$('.ice-previous').click (function () {
$li = $('ul.ice-navigator li'); //get the list of li's

//move the 1st element clone to the last position in copy_li
$copy_li.splice(0, 0, $li.eq(elToShow-1).clone()); //array.splice(index,howmany,element1,.....,elementX)

//kill the 1st element in the UL
$li.eq(elToShow-1).remove();

//add to the last
$ul.prepend($copy_li.pop());

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/devsvits/hV5DA/

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it...

You stick your advance code in a function and call it as many times as images you want to advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/hV5DA/1/

```
$('.ice-next').click (function () {

  function nextItem(){
        $li = $('ul.ice-navigator li'); //get the list of li's
       //move the 1st element clone to the last position in copy_li
        $copy_li.splice(copy_lgt, 0, $li.eq(0).clone() ); //array.splice(index,howmany,element1,.....,elementX)

        //kill the 1st element in the UL
        $li.eq(0).remove();

        //add to the last
        $ul.append($copy_li.shift());
  } 

    //number of items to replace   
    var numItemsToAdvance = 3;    

    //call function n times
    while(numItemsToAdvance--){
        nextItem();
    }
});
```